UK Standard Visitor visa - Should I say that I don't have any savings account if I only have chequing accounts?
I am a permanent resident of Canada and I am currently in the process of applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa. I have gathered all the required documents, but I am a bit confused on one thing. In the income and expenditure section, it is asking me if I have any other source of income or savings.
My situation is as follows, I am currently employed full-time and I have two bank accounts in different banks, both are chequing accounts. My current salary is deposited to one of my chequing accounts regularly every month. As for my other chequing account, that's the one where my salary used to be deposited to when I worked at a different company.
In my case above, does it mean that I should choose the option "I don't have any other income or savings", since I only have chequing accounts, and explain so in a last section of my application?
Also, as for my financial proofs, I have my bank statements, payslips, and employment letter that can prove that I have a stable income, with stable expenses.
Please help me clear my confusion, as per my understanding, chequing accounts are not considered savings accounts.
Thanks in advance.

The question is not just about "savings accounts" but about any vehicle in which you save money (eg an rrsp, an investment account that you buy stocks from, etc) and about other income (rent from a building you own, a second job or side hustle, etc.)  If you have listed both the bank accounts in which you might have some money, and the one job that you have, then it seems likely that "I don't have any other income or savings" is correct, but if you have money in some other thing, then don't say you don't.

@KateGregory Thank you. Yes, I just want to make sure that I'm being truthful in my application.
